# substring extracting in groovy from another string

Tags: groovy

I have a string:

```
pRoiGroup="[com.testing.Location#533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25]"
```

I want to get the string `"533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25"` from `pRoiGrop`. how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def result= pRoiGroup.split("#")[1][0..-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = pRoiGroup - "[com.testing.Location#" - "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
def result = pRoiGroup.find( /#([a-f0-9]*)]/ ) { it[ 1 ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pRoiGroup[++pRoiGroup.indexOf(/#/)..-2] //No list involved
```