# substring extracting in groovy with grails from another string

Tags: groovy

I have a string `pRoiGroup="[com.testing.Location#533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25]"` in groovy. I want to get the string `"533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25"` from `pRoiGrop`. May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [substring extracting in groovy from another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905327/substring-extracting-in-groovy-from-another-string)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
def pRoiGroup = "[com.testing.Location#533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25]"
def part = pRoiGroup.tokenize("#")[1].replaceAll("]", "")
println part
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Straighforward

As Array

```
def pRoiGroup="[com.testing.Location#533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25]"
def string = pRoiGroup.split('#')
def finalString = string[1].replace("]", "")
// finalString will be 533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25
```

OR do this as an ArrayList like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906303/2414129

```
def pRoiGroup="[com.testing.Location#533bfa78d3f9645043e4eb25]"
def resultList = pRoiGroup.tokenize('#')
def finalString = resultList.get(1).replace("]", "")
```